# Why is the current version of Eclipse called Galileo?

Tags: eclipse

It's silly, but I've been wondering about this for some time.  Eclipse 3.2 was Callisto, 3.3 was Europa, and 3.4 was Ganymede, so why wasn't 3.5 Io instead of Galileo? Was it the risk of being confused with I/O?

On a related note, it looks like 3.6 will be called Helios.  How did we wind up there instead of moving to, say, moons of Saturn?

I just wondered if anybody knew the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Because they skipped Io for being confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions were taken and voted on, "Galileo" was the winner.  You can see the discussion in [bug 235189](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=235189).

Similarly, for this year's [Helios](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=271054).

Comment: I was thinking there were going for the other 62 known satellites.